# Find the average rate of change of $f(x) = x^2 - 3x-2$ on the interval [2,5]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey guys I need some help with this problem its been giving me some trouble I've tried a lot of different ways but I can't find the answer.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempts.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: The average rate of change of $f(x)$ on the interval $a\le x\le b$ is just ${f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}$.

Answer (score 3):

That should be $\frac{f(5)-f(2)}{5-2}=\frac{5^2-3\cdot 5-2-(2^2-3\cdot 2-2)}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Rate of change of $f(x)$ is $f'(x).$ So, the average rate of change is-
$$
\frac{\int_2^5 f'(x)dx}{\int_2^5 dx} \ = \frac{f(x)\huge|_{\small{2}}^{\small{5}}
}{x\huge|_{\small{2}}^{\small{5}}}=\frac{f(5)-f(2)}{5-2}=\frac{8+4}{3}=4$$